# Why am I not seeing hibernate proxy objects in my ManyToOne associations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy, hibernate-mapping

According the the hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-proxies), my `@ManyToOne` relationships should have proxy objects by default. However, when I look at an expanded object in the Eclipse debugger ("Variables" view), it looks like the field variables are instances of the base type as defined in the entity class. Moreover, when I call `session.get(type, id)` with `hibernate.show_sql=true` I can see `left outer join`s for all `@ManyToOne` relationships defined on the object.

Is there something specific that needs done in order for Hibernate to create proxy classes/objects for these relationships? Perhaps bytecode enhancement?

Quote from hibernate docs:

> Lazy fetching for collections is implemented using Hibernate's own
>   implementation of persistent collections. However, a different
>   mechanism is needed for lazy behavior in single-ended associations.
>   The target entity of the association must be proxied. Hibernate
>   implements lazy initializing proxies for persistent objects using
>   runtime bytecode enhancement which is accessed via the bytecode
>   provider.
>
> At startup, Hibernate generates proxies by default for all persistent
>   classes and uses them to enable lazy fetching of many-to-one and
>   one-to-one associations.

Comment: Make the association lazy

Comment: @JBNizet - thanks, how do i do that? Also, why do the docs say it should happen by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` associations are [EAGER by default](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/), that's why they are JOINED when you fetch the root entity.

A proxy is used only if the association is not initialized. To make your associations LAZY, you just need to add the LAZY fetch attribute:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, just one question: when would an association be not initialised (and therefore appear as a proxy)? It seems to me, according to the docs (updated question with quote) that all many-to-one associations should be proxies by default - though I must be misunderstanding something..

Comment: The documentation is clear. For x-to-one associations, proxies are used if the association is LAZY. The proxy is implemented using [runtime bytecode enhancement](https://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/jpa-enhancement-done-right/).